# Expressing a String

Tags: string, vb.net, expression

I cannot find a way to express a string. So for example if I type the string `" ""Hello "" & 10*20/(21/2) & "" World"" "` In a `Textbox` control or `Console.ReadLine()` input it should return `Hello 19,0476190476191 World`. Can I do this?

Comment: You can use the Roslyn compiler: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes and `+` as the string concatenation character, you can abuse the expression evaluation engine of ADO.NET:

```
Dim expression As String = " 'Hello ' + 10*20/(21/2) + ' World' "
Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(expression, Nothing)

' Prints: Hello 19.047619047619 World
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

The [`DataColumn.Expression` MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) has a list of all supported operators.

(On the other hand, writing a simple Basic expression parser is always a fun exercise, so don't let that stop you.)

Comment: Is there any way that I can use the "&" and the dobule quote symbol becuase it drops an expection?

Comment: @codiee: Not with the DataTable expression parser. You might have more luck if you manage to somehow call the VBScript evaluator from .NET, but I have never tried that.